# How to make a list of a certain length

Tags: python, list

If I want to make an empty list that is a certain length, how do I create it without having to manually type the brackets. For example: If I want to have a list with a length of 32 but I don't want to have to type [ , , , , , ...] until the 32nd element, how would I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly do it as -

```
empty_list = [None]*32
print(empty_list)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

The above will create a list of size 32, where each element of the list is initialized to None.

You can also do it as -

```
empty_list = [None for _ in range(32)]
```

The above code would also give the same result as before

Comment: It should be noted that the first solution shouldn't be used for any initialized value: they will all point to the same object. For example: `a = [[]] * 10` will actually have a list point to the same empty list 10 times. The two ways shown do not always provide the same results, just with `None`.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
a = numpy.empty(32, str).tolist()
```

or:

```
a = [‘’]*32
```